# Meaning of "that friendship will not continue to the end which is begun for an end"

Tags: meaning, quotes

Can someone explain the meaning of this quotation?

> That friendship will not continue to the end which is begun for an end.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In this case

> ... for an end

is used to mean ["for a purpose"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to_what_end). Another example of this use case is "to what end", or "means to an end".

Knowing this, the meaning of the quote is clear:

If you become friends with someone in order to get something (or any purpose other than friendship), that friendship will not last life-long (or as the quote says, "continue to the end").

Answer (score 4):

> That friendship will not continue to the end which is begun for an end.

It might be clearer to you if we rearrange this sentence into a more normal order:

> That friendship which is begun for an end, will not continue to the end.

As others have said, "for an end" means "for a purpose (other than friendship)".

Answer (score 3):

Quote is easier to follow when broken in parts:

> That friendship will not continue to the end

Meaning - The friendship will not last.

> which is begun for an end.

Meaning - If the friendship was started for other reasons/ulterior motives..

**If a friendship that started out for other(not sincere) reasons then that friendship will not last till the end.**

Comment: Please use block quoting (>) for English text, not `code`-style quoting.

Answer (score 1):

A friendship for something(money, power, etc.) will not last long.

Answer (score 0):

Friendship that is started for purpose will not last.

Meaning that friendship should have no purpose.

Comment: Not all purposes can be described by the term "end".  A better explanation, IMO, is that (the purpose of) friendship should be the journey, not the destination.